# Configuring tab with specific URL within Facebook Fan Page using app_data

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

The Facebook API docs say the parameter, "app_data," should be used to customize tabs within a Facebook Fan Page.

However, when users add our tab to their page, the "app_data" param gets lost every time, meaning the tabs aren't customized per Fan Page as they should be.

For instance, we want this page to get rendered for one client: http://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=198939416792674&sk=app_198939416792674&app_data=15

After the client adds this URL as a tab to his Fan Page, though, the tab URL loses the "app_data" parameter. The page rendered no longer reflects the data specific to this client.

We need the tabs to contain a parameter specific to each Fan Page. We thought "app_data" was the right approach.

Any clues what we're doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do what you trying to achieve is to customise the content based on the `page['id']` that is passed to you via a [signed request](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/).

Comment: Thanks. We're aware of this method, but we prefer the app_data method as it allows us to leverage the existing data model. What is the purpose of the app_data parameter if not for this? Do we misunderstand its purpose?

Comment: Well the URL of the tab is defined in your app's settings, not by the page admin, so you wouldn't be able to have a per page URL anyway. `app_data` is if you're linking directly to the tab from somewhere else.

Comment: Thanks, Colm. So you're basically saying the only option is to modify the schema and link the page ID to each client?

Comment: Well, it's certainly the only way I've ever used. That's not to say there's not a better approach, I've just never investigated one since the method I've outlined always worked for me.

Comment: Thanks, Colm. If the app_data parameter cannot be pegged to the URL as we assumed, then this seems like the best approach. What confused us was this sentence in the Facebook docs: "In addition, your application will also receive a string parameter called app_data as part of signed_request if an app_data parameter was set in the original query string in the URL your tab is loaded on." From the context on this page (http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462/), it seems like the app_data gets stored when an admin adds an app to a Facebook Fan Page. Are we reading this wrong?

Comment: The app_data is only for links from external websites as far as I know.  It's not passed from the page the admin adds the app from, but from the business page the app tab is loaded on.  That being said, I would love to see it work the way you are trying to make it work.